# Subset rows in List using an apply function family

Tags: r, list, subset, apply, lapply

This is a bit of a general question, how do I show the first couple of rows of each element of my list using an apply function. I understand I would have to use lapply but I am confused what function I would use inside of it

```
# I have tried this but I did not work. 
lapply( data.list , "[" ,1:3)
```

Comment: Try `lapply( data.list , function(x) x[1:2,])`

Comment: Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 0):

By extractors, if we don't use `,`, it will consider that as column index

```
lapply(data.list, `[`, 1:3, )
```

Or another option is to make use of `head`

```
lapply(data.list, head, 3)
```

#### data

```
data.list <- list(head(mtcars), head(mtcars))
```